# Full Firebase React-native app to offline persistance

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an app that is working perfectly. but online only. I am using react-redux and redux for backend, but everytime I create data to Firebase, the data is automatically stored to the action.payload. I want to make my app offline first and If the user is connected to the internet, I want the data to be stored in Firebase. The thing is that I don't want to take it from 0, I want to remake the fetch, create delete actions but for the local store not for the Firebase directly. What should I use to make it work offline and at the same time to not be obligated to remake the app from scratch.

Comment: refer [can firebase work offline with react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593310/can-firebase-work-offline-with-react-native)